# Surface area of cone

Tags: calculus, area

thanks for any help.

I'm trying to find the surface area of a cone via integration. 
I know that the parametric equation of a cone is $$x=u\cos(p) \\ y=u\sin(p) \\ z=u$$

So as a vector, $\vec{R} = \langle u\cos(p), u \sin(p), u \rangle$.

Since the area equals the double integral of $ds$, and $d\vec{s} = \dfrac{d\vec{R}}{du} du \times \dfrac{d\vec{R}}{dp} dp$, I work out that:

$$\vec{ds} = u\,du \, dp \, \langle -\cos(p),-\sin(p),1\rangle \\ ds = n \, d\vec{s} \\ ds = u \, du \, dp $$

I would expect I'd get the correct answer if I integrated this between the limits 0 to $2\pi$ and 0 to $h$, however I get $h^2\pi$ which is incorrect. Could someone point me to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. For some basic information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latexhelp/notation).

Answer (score 4):

You actually had just about everything right, except that you skipped an important step:  your normal vector to the surface $ \ \vec{ds} \ $ is correct, but you need to integrate its *length* over the surface of the cone nappe in order to obtain the surface area.

I'll generalize the problem a little, since the choice of proportions for the cone hides one of the factors in the surface area result.  For a cone nappe with a height $ \ h \ $ and a "base radius" $ \ r \ $ , we can use similar triangles to find the parametrization (using your notation)

$$ x \ = \ \left( \frac{r}{h} \right) u \ \cos \ p \ \ , \ \ y \ = \ \left( \frac{r}{h} \right) u \ \sin \ p \ \ , \ \ z \ =  \ u \ \ , $$

with the domain $ \ 0 \ \le \ u \ \le \ h \ , \ 0 \ \le \ p \ < \ 2 \pi \ $ .  An "upward" normal vector is then given by

$$ \vec{R_u} \ \times \ \vec{R_p} \ \ " = " \ \ \left|\begin{array}{ccc}\mathbf{i}&\mathbf{j}&\mathbf{k}\\ \left( \frac{r}{h} \right)  \cos \ p&\left( \frac{r}{h} \right) \sin \ p\quad&1\\ -\left( \frac{r}{h} \right) u \ \sin \ p&\left( \frac{r}{h} \right) u \ \cos \ p\quad&0\end{array}\right|   $$

$$ = \ \langle \ -\left( \frac{r}{h} \right) u \ \cos \ p  \ \ , \ \ -\left( \frac{r}{h} \right) u \ \sin \ p  \ \ , \ \ \left( \frac{r}{h} \right)^2 u   \  \rangle \ \ .  $$

So, up to this point, your procedure is fine.  What is needed now is the "norm" of this vector:

$$ \| \ \vec{R_u} \ \times \ \vec{R_p} \ \| \ \  =  \  \ \left[ \ \left( \frac{r}{h} \right)^2 u^2 \ \cos^2 \ p  \ + \ \left( \frac{r}{h} \right)^2 u^2 \ \sin^2 \ p  \ + \ \left( \frac{r}{h} \right)^4 u^2 \  \right]^{1/2} \ \ .  $$

$$ =  \  \ \left[ \ \left( \frac{r}{h} \right)^2 u^2 \  + \ \left( \frac{r}{h} \right)^4 u^2 \  \right]^{1/2} \ = \ \left(\frac{r}{h} \right)  \ \sqrt{ 1 \  + \ \left( \frac{r}{h} \right)^2  } \ \ u  \ \ . $$

It is the "magnitude" of the infinitesimal patches associated with the normal vectors that we wish to integrate over the domain of the parameters.  Thus,

$$ S \ \ = \ \ \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^h \ \left(\frac{r}{h} \right)  \ \sqrt{ 1 \  + \ \left( \frac{r}{h} \right)^2  } \ \ u \ \ du \ dp $$

$$ = \ \ \left(\frac{r}{h} \right)  \ \sqrt{ 1 \  + \ \left( \frac{r}{h} \right)^2  } \ \int_0^{2 \pi} dp \ \int_0^h \  u \ \ du   $$

$$ = \ \left(\frac{r}{h} \right)  \ \sqrt{ 1 \  + \ \left( \frac{r}{h} \right)^2  } \ \cdot \ 2 \pi \ \cdot \ \left(\frac{1}{2}u^2 \right) \vert_0^h \ \ = \ \left(\frac{r}{h} \right)  \ \sqrt{ 1 \  + \ \left( \frac{r}{h} \right)^2  } \ \cdot \  \pi \ h^2  $$

$$ = \ \pi \ h \ \cdot \ \left(\frac{r}{h} \right)  \ \cdot \ h \ \sqrt{ 1 \  + \ \left( \frac{r}{h} \right)^2  } \ = \ \pi \ r \ \sqrt{ r^2 \  + \  h^2  } \ \ , $$

or $ \ \pi \ $ times the "base radius" times the "slant height" of the cone nappe, as the surface area is frequently expressed.  In your use of the "standard cone", for which $ \ r \ = \ h  \ $ , this formula gives us $ \ S \ = \ \pi \ \sqrt{2} \ h^2 \ $ , as you will find for your calculations, with the restoration of the omitted step.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
Put the surface of the cone in a plane. It becomes  a 'pie/pizza slice' with
$$
\mbox{radius}\quad
R_{\rm pie}\equiv \root{r^{2} + h^{2}}
\qquad\mbox{and}\qquad\mbox{angle}\quad
\Delta\theta \equiv {2\pi r \over \root{r^{2} + h^{2}}}
$$

> \begin{align}
> \color{#f44}{\large\mbox{Surface}}
> =\half\,R_{\rm pie}^{2}\,\Delta\theta
> =\half\,\pars{\root{r^{2} + h^{2}}}^{2}{2\pi r \over \root{r^{2} + h^{2}}}
> =\color{#f44}{{\large\pi r\root{r^{2} + h^{2}}}}
> \end{align}