# Surface Area of Multiple Integration

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the area of the upper half of the cone $x^2+y^2=z^2$ above the interior of one loop of $r=cos(2\theta)$.

I know the formula for surface area is $\int_{x_0}^{x_1}\int_{y_0}^{y_1}\sqrt{(f_x)^2+(f_y)^2+1}dxdy$, and in this question it should be $\int_{x_0}^{x_1}\int_{y_0}^{y_1}\sqrt{(\frac{-2x}{2\sqrt{-y^2-x^2}})^2+(\frac{-2y}{2\sqrt{-y^2-x^2}})^2+1}dxdy$, but I am not sure about the bounds.  I am guessing that since I'm only taking the area above one loop of $r=cos(2\theta)$, that the bound for $x$ goes from $0$ to $1$.  What about the bounds for $y$?  Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Expand and simplify the expression under the root sign, after correcting the negative signs of $y^2$ and $x^2$.

Comment: @random I know how to do the actual integral, but I'm confused as to what the bounds should be.

Comment: Doing everything in polar coordinates is an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cylindrical coordinates it gets simpler. [The surface element for this cone](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/843027/362604) with the parametrization $\vec s=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,r)$ is $\mathbb dS=\sqrt{2}r\,\mathbb dr\,\mathbb d\theta$. So

$$S=\dfrac14\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\cos(2\theta)}\sqrt2r\,\mathbb dr\,\mathbb d\theta$$

The factor 1/4 is because the graph of the curve has four equal lobes.